# how to put day month and year in single and double quotes when fetching from database in java

Tags: jsp, servlets

String first1=request.getParameter("from_date");
        String Second2=request.getParameter("to_date");

```
    String[] str=first1.split("/");
    String[] str1= Second2.split("/");

    int month=Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int day=Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    int year=Integer.parseInt(str[2]);

    int month1=Integer.parseInt(str1[0]);
    int day1=Integer.parseInt(str1[1]);
    int year1=Integer.parseInt(str1[2]);

    System.out.println("From Date :-- Day is:"+day+ "-Month is:"+month+ "-Year is:"+year);
    System.out.println("End Date :-- Day is:"+day1+ "-Month is:"+month1+ "-Year is:"+year1);
```

rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM frt WHERE  (dateinc >= '"+month+"/"+day+"/"+year"'&& dateinc <='"+month1+"/"+day1+"/"+year1'")");

Comment: rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM frt WHERE (dateinc >= '"+month+"/"+day+"/"+year"'&& dateinc <='"+month1+"/"+day1+"/"+year1'")");                          // in this query m not sure...where to put single(') and where to put double quotes ("). please help OR please tell me is it a right way to do it ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what is it you are trying to achieve but i believe this method will make your code more readable and easier to edit in the future.

```
String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
String date1 = month1 + "/" + day1 + "/" + year1;

String sql = "SELECT * FROM frt WHERE (dateinc > = " + date + " AND dateinc <= " + date1 + ")";

rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Else you are inviting SQLInjection attacks. It also allows for easier type conversion and readability of your query syntax.